# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, variables, react-router

[This is the rejection error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vqHt.png)

Here's where the trouble started to occur "Routes.js":

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Router, Stack, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';



export default class Routes extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <Stack key="root">
                    <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
                    <Scene key="register" component={Signup} title="Register"/>
                </Stack>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

Then made changes in the "App.js" file to import from Routes

    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 * @lint-ignore-every XPLATJSCOPYRIGHT1
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { 
        StyleSheet,
        View,
        StatusBar
      } from 'react-native';

import Routes from './src/Routes';




export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar 
            backgroundColor="#0086c3" 
            barStyle="light-content"
          />
        <Routes/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    backgroundColor: '#29b6f6',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }

});
```

I'm not too sure what's going on, I saved all the files and have it on Hot Reloading but still shows this error. I'm new to React Native and am still learning its fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your `Login` route before you use it. ie:

```
import Login from './path-to-routes/Login';
```

Comment: this is what I currently have based on where I created the file. [import Login from './src/pages/Login']. Should I put this in my App.js file or the Routes.js file? I tried both and still didn't seem to work, still getting the same rejection.

Comment: I don't see any import statement that's importing Login in your Routes.js files. In your routes.js file add a `console.log(Login)` and make sure it exists, and is a component. This is where your issue lies

Comment: Here's the Routes.js file so far. Is this correct?  import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Router, Stack, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Login from './src/pages/Login'

console.log(Login)

export default class Routes extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <Stack key="root">
                    <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
                    <Scene key="register" component={Signup} title="Register"/>
                </Stack>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

Comment: You should edit your question to include the relevant updates. Do you see anything in your console? If it's showing undefined, then make sure you're exporting the component in `./src/pages/Login`

Comment: I’ll give that a try, and thank you, I’m new to stackoverflow so still getting used to it.